GStreamer plugin gssink not included
I am trying to use the plugin gssink in my gstreamer pipeline on Ubuntu 22.04. It's part of the gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad package. I've installed all of the gst packages
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
    gstreamer1.0-libav \
    gstreamer1.0-tools \
    gstreamer1.0-alsa \
    gstreamer1.0-gl \
    gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio \

When I do a gst-inspect-1.0 gssink I get No such element or plugin 'gssink'. 
Same thing with gst-inspect-1.0 gssrc.
I know that some of the "bad" plugins are being included because gst-inspect-1.0 ipcpipeline returns a hit and it is part of gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad.
I know that gssink is included in my version because it was added in version 1.20 and gst-launch-1.0 --version gives GStreamer 1.20.3 .
I am aware that due to being in the "bad" plugins that they are not maintained to the same standard as other plugins or have licensing issues but for my use case it should be sufficient. I know the source code is there. Where can I include gs and gssink? I've tried to build from source with little success.

You should check with Ubuntu if that plugin is provided. Just that it is added to GStreamer does not neccesarily mean that it is packaged downstream.

It seems the library needed is not included in any ubuntu distro, you might want to build the plugin from source
